# Redirección htaccess subdominio a URL estática manteniendo URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirección, dominio

Estoy intentando realizar una redirección desde `subdominio.dominio.es` a `dominio.es/test` en htaccess. La redirección funciona bien, pero necesito que en la barra de direcciones se mantenga la dirección `subdominio.dominio.es`. Tanto el dominio como el subdominio están en el mismo servidor. La URL `dominio.es/test` es una URL estática que siempre va a ser la misma.

Hasta ahora, esto es lo que tengo en mi htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdominio.dominio.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dominio.es/testing/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

¿Cómo podría mantener la URL que deseo en la barra de direcciones y que la redirección se haga de manera correcta?

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacer un ProxyPass en vez de un redirect, pero para que funcione correctamente el servidor debe poder acceder a la url definitiva.

Seria cambiarlo por esto:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdominio.dominio.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dominio.es/testing/$1 [P]
```

Comment: He probado esto, pero me aparece un error 404 en esa página. Aparte, también he visto que no me aparece HTTPS en la dirección.

Comment: Son temas diferentes y bastante mas complicado de lo que parece. Para poder navegar por `subdominio.dominio.es` con https tienes que configurarlo en el vhost que controla ese subdominio... La regla del RewriteRule lo que hace es hacer de proxy entre `subdominio.dominio.es` y `https://www.dominio.es` pero necesitas que este todo bien configurado para que puedas acceder a la url `https://www.dominio.es` desde el servidor (p.e. con wget). Ademas, una cosa muy importante es que la apllcacion que haya en `www.dominio.es` este preparada para utilizarse a traves de proxypass.